# Queue array implementation: dequeue function

Tags: c, queue

Stuck on the problem with array queue dequeue function implementation.
It seems that the function itself is correct, but the problem is as far as I understand the pointer in parameters. Why do I exit with Segmentation fault here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define CAPACITY 3

typedef struct {
        int head;
        int size;
        int elements[CAPACITY];
        } queue;

bool isempty(queue* q);
int size(queue* q);
bool enqueue(queue* q, int element);
bool dequeue(queue* q, int* element);


int main(void) {

queue q;

if(isempty(&q)) {
    printf("Queue is empty\n");
}

enqueue(&q, 34);
enqueue(&q, 2);
enqueue(&q, 4);
dequeue(&q, &q.head);

if(!isempty(&q)) {
    printf("Queue is not empty\n");
}

printf("%i\n", q.elements[1]);

}

bool isempty(queue* q) {
    return q->size == 0;
}

int size(queue* q) {
    return q->size;
}

bool enqueue(queue* q, int element) {

    if(q->size < CAPACITY) {
        q->elements[(q->head + q->size) % CAPACITY] = element;
        q->size++;
        printf("Enqueue: %d\n", element);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool dequeue(queue* q, int* element) {

    if(q->size > 0) {
        *element = q->elements[q->head];
        q->head = (q->head+1) % CAPACITY;
        q->size--;

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. At a minimum it will tell you exactly which line is triggering the seg fault. And much more.

Comment: `queue q;` that is an uninitialised variable. It contains junk values. All bets are off from that point on.

Comment: To begin with, you may need to have one more function like createqueue where you initialize the queue.